# How to get the return value from a smart contract method execution

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js

I have [ERC-20](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard) token smart-contract which methods I call using [`sendSignedTransaction`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html?highlight=sendSignedTransaction#sendsignedtransaction) from web3.js. After I know transaction is succesfully mined I need to check contract method execution result. How do I do it if all I have is transaction hash?

Example: method `transferFrom(from, to, tokens)` returns `true` or `false` depending on whether transferring was successful. So if I try to transfer 100 tokens from empty wallet, contract method will return `false`.

As I understand, there is no way of determining method outcome using txHash after transaction is mined and confirmed. Then which ways exists to handle this case? How can I make sure that tokens were transferred?

Comment: Transactions don't have return values, so although the function returns a boolean, that value is not persisted anywhere. But you can look for events that were logged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can emit an event inside your contract code ( actually in ERC20 standard there is always a transfer event present ) and then inside web3js, read all the events till latest block using this line of code:

`Events = Contract.eventName({}, {fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});`

Comment: Yep, this is what I came to. Also you may want not to check events from block 0 everytime (because such check takes significant amount of time to execute), buy save somewhere a block number of the last check. And next time only process events that were fired after that block number.

Comment: "...save somewhere a block number of the last check." You can just get the latest block number before you call `transferFrom`, right?

Comment: Yes, I think this is a better way to go. You may even have a hash-map of `transferFrom` transactions hashes to `Transfer Event` hashes.